# How to set environment variable in postman collection runner?

Tags: collections, automated-tests, postman, web-api-testing, postman-collection-runner

I have an API named *getcampaignlist*. It returns me all campaign list with descriptions according to relevant person. Like in image I have multiple campaign with id and description. I want to set environment variable using

"`postman.setEnvironmentVariable("cmid", jsonData.id)`;"
or

"`postman.setEnvironmentVariable("cmid", jsonData.id)`
where
`jsonData.campaignName==="online Games "`; "

[image: For clarification check image]

I mean I want to use all these id's in loop through collection runner. how can I set values in environment variable. Because when I set jsonData.id it can't decide which id value should be set in environment variable "cmid" and return false.

Comment: What do you mean by "return false"? Do you have `var jsonData = pm.response.json()` in the test tab where you have your `postman.setEnvironmentVariable("cmid", jsonData.id)` code? Also, this wouldn't get anything as it's an array so `jsonData[0].id` would get the first `id` in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *collection runner*, you would normally [use data files](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files) (csv or json), and access the variables with `data`, for example `data.id`.

Answer (score 2):

This code can be added to the `Tests` tab to iterate over the response data (similar to your example) and assign the ID that matches `Online Games` as an environment variable. This can be referenced in another request by using the `{{cmid}}` in the URL.

```
const result = pm.response.json()

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; ++i)
     if (result[i].campaignName === "Online Games") {
         pm.environment.set('cmid', result[i].id)
     }
```

Example using Postman:

[image: API Response]